How to use ocaml library set to make data structure archive?
I am using the functional approach to programming learn ocaml. I coded an example about graph.
code link here
In this case, I used a list to represent the an archive.
type comparison = Smaller | Equiv | Greater
type 'a archive = {archlist:'a list; comp:'a->'a->comparison}

let add_to_archive arch elem =
  if List.exists (fun t -> arch.comp t elem == Equiv) arch.archlist then
    arch
  else
    { archlist = elem::arch.archlist; comp = arch.comp }

let add_list_to_archive:'a archive -> 'a list -> 'a archive = fun arch elemlst ->
  List.fold_left (fun a t -> add_to_archive a t) arch elemlst

let make_archive comp lst =
  let arch = {archlist = []; comp = comp} in
  add_list_to_archive arch lst

let archive_member elem arch =
  List.exists (fun t -> arch.comp t elem = Equiv) arch.archlist

let archive_map arch_part f (arch,l) =
  let rec arch_map arch ll = function
    [] -> (arch,ll)
  | (c::cl) ->
      let ll' = select
                  (fun c -> not (archive_member (arch_part c) arch)) (f c) in
      arch_map (add_list_to_archive arch (List.map arch_part ll')) (ll'@ll) cl in
  arch_map arch [] l

I think this implementation maybe a performance bottleneck for my case. Maybe I can use the standard library Set to implement the archive data structure. But it seems I need to specify the type of data structure in set. Is there a way I can keep the interface with archive data structure and change the implementation to Ocaml standard library Set.
Can you give an implementation to use Ocaml standard library Set to implement the archive data structure. It's okay to give just some part of the code. I will do the rest.
type comparison = Smaller | Equiv | Greater
type 'a archive = { archlist : 'a list; comp : 'a -> 'a -> comparison; }
val add_to_archive : 'a archive -> 'a -> 'a archive = <fun>
val add_list_to_archive : 'a archive -> 'a list -> 'a archive = <fun>
val make_archive : ('a -> 'a -> comparison) -> 'a list -> 'a archive = <fun>
val archive_member : 'a -> 'a archive -> bool = <fun>
val archive_map :
  ('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a list) -> 'b archive * 'c list -> 'b archive * 'a list =
  <fun>


It looks like your archive type is simply implementing a set, but using lists, which have O(n) access complexity, while sets as defined in the OCaml standard library are backed by a balanced binary search tree and have O(log n) lookup complexity. This will make a tremendous difference in scaling. Wrapping sets to create your type should be straightforward.

Note that archlist is polymorphic, so you can consider using a functor:
module Graph = 
  functor (Archlist : sig 
      type t 
      val compare : t -> t -> int
    end) ->
    struct
      type comparison = Smaller | Equiv | Greater
      
      module Archlist_set = Set.Make(Archlist)

      type archive = { 
        archlist: Archlist_set.t; 
        comp: Archlist.t -> Archlist.t -> comparison
      }
    end

then:
module Int_graph = Graph(Int)

